# Xpath element not interractable issue. Selenium,Java

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, automation, automated-tests

I have been trying to access a search bar and submit the query which doesnot have a SEARCH BUTTON, as I Could enter the search query using javascriptexecutor, I Couldnot do an enter button action as It doesnot have any enter button. so I have went with the following ways and none of them worked. Please consider and correct me.

I have tried to do an enter key action on the search bar. the code is as followed
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="mobile-header"]/div[3]/input").sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);`
and
`WebElement search = bd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mobile-header\"]/div[3]/input")); search.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);`

and `in the following code the value is passed but the enter key is not working
`JavascriptExecutor jj= (JavascriptExecutor)bd;`
`jj.executeScript("arguments[0].value='mercury'", search);`
`jj.executeScript("arguments[0].value=Keys.Return", search);`

none of the seems to work. correct if i have my xpath wrong. thanks

Comment: Why not just click the search button? Can you share URL?

Comment: @pburgr There is no search button. URL : https://www.boat-lifestyle.com/?utm_source=affiliates&utm_medium=Optimise&utm_campaign=Optimise_jan2021

Comment: Based what exactly has to be tested you can simply construct URL ../search?q=watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='st-search-box hidden-mobile-only']//input[@type='text']").sendKeys("headphones);
    ActionChains(driver).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
```

[DOM snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfK6G.png)

Comment: there seems to be an issue with ActionChains(driver) portion, it says undefined for type find. though without that line, I got the result I just used the line to apply enter button. thank you so much. Though can you help me how did you sort the xpath?

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry for that. I am predominantly a python guy so syntax may differ here and there, but the crux is the same. Glad it helped!
Regarding Xpath, I just checked in the browser. If you do not know, then you may `SHIFT + F12` (in windows, not sure about mac), and you'd get the developer tools window. Go to the tab, `Inspector` in Firefox, or `Elements` in case of Chrome, and there you can build any of your locator, like xpath, css_selector, etc.

Comment: i got a different xpath there, which i mentioned, i just want to know how to create xpath.

Comment: @keshuthilakan I have updated the DOM snapshot in the answer